# Как избежать изменения двух массивов одновременно?

Tags: javascript

Есть код:

```
n = output.push(objects[0][i]) - 1;
output[n].link = "/img/blank.gif";
```

При его выполнение изменяется как `output[n].link`, так и `objects[0][i].link`

Как мне избежать изменения переменной `objects[0][i].link`?

`objects.slice()[0][i]` не помогло

**ДОБАВЛЕНО:**
Я пушу элементы массива А в массив Б. Затем я изменяю только что добавленный элемент массива Б. При этом у меня изменяется элемент массива А, чего мне не надо. Вопрос: Как этого избежать?

Проще говоря, я хочу вернуть пользователю измененный массив, не изменяя его на сервере.

Comment: Вы здесь делаете что-то весьма странное, кажется Вы вообще плохо понимаете что делаете. Крайне рекомендую почитать какой-нибудь учебник по js для новичков прежде чем браться за ноду. learn.javascript.ru скажем. Потому что вопрос показывает непонимание самых базовых принципов js.

Comment: Опишите в общем саму задачу лучше (что Вы хотите этим кодом сделать).

Comment: Я не пойму что вы хотите сделать? Выложите ваш массив и что вы хотите с ним сделать

Comment: изменил вопрос.

Comment: А почему нельзя клонировать массив? Или вам нужно именно отдельные компоненты?

Comment: просто надо объяснить человеку, что в массивах хранятся ссылки на один и тот же объект

Comment: @Igor ну я это и так понимаю, вопрос, как этого избежать

Comment: @Yuri нужны только отдельные компоненты массива

Comment: @Igor, помимо этого надо понять почему он скажем n довольно странно считает. Вот про Object.assign Вы написали, а он уже в IE11 без полифилла - не работает. Так что либо рассказывать про полифиллы-бабель-вот-это-все (что при непонимании уже передачи по ссылке может вызвать затруднения), либо выпросить задачу и попытаться решить ее без сложностей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

```
n = output.push(Object.assign({}, objects[0][i])) - 1;
output[n].link = "/img/blank.gif";
```

Comment: да, это работает, большое спасибо

Comment: @Rundik, учтите что не сработает просто так в любом IE и кажется в сафари.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму я в node.js это использую

Comment: @Rundik, ну в ноде проблемы если будут то только раньше четверки, то есть в сильно старой.